# Difference in Tactics Ratings

Tags: tactics, rating

I have a Chess.com tactics rating (default blitz setting where time to solve is instrumental in getting points)  hovering around 1750 but for some reason I can't get beyond 1550 on the Chess Tempo's Chess-Tactics site on the standard rating scale (no time limit). Any reason why?  Is it only because the blitz capability and the no-time-limit capability are different, or because the problem difficulty ratings in these two websites are different?

Comment: Do they use the same rating system? I'm guessing not, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I am not sure.  But the problems feel different.  The Chess .com problems at this level demand bold moves and clear lines (at least they appear to do so to me).  The Chess Tempo tactics problems usually are set with a trap after the first major move -- it usually involves a strong distractor which I usually fall for, or there is a key Zwischenzug which  manages to hold on to material more strongly.  The Chess Tempo problems I find are also much harder to see.

Comment: In my experience the chesstempo problems are the toughest (of those easily available) out there. That's juts a feeling, so can't give a well supported answer. Anyway, ratings are already hardly comparable for playing games on different online sites. Tactics ratings are probably even less comparable. Anyway, you should focus on improving (i.e. the trend) not on absolute numbers when it comes to rating.

Comment: Tactics ratings on different online sites can vary wildly. You could be well over master level on chess.com tactics but be under 1800.

Answer (score 2):

Different sites will have different rating systems, even for games!

So, for tactical puzzles, basically every site works in a completely different manner. Also, I don't know about chess.com, but in chesstempo, different settings will also result in different ratings, as the kind of puzzles will be different, and the balance is not perfectly achieved.

Comment: Thanks David,  user1583209 and Glorfindel.  These are real time answers -- meaning they don't answer the question, but they tell me what's important.  Keep the trend up and don't worry about absolute numbers.  I am an older (65) beginner and have been working up steadily over the past two years from about 1200 up to these current numbers.  I have been putting away playing actual games for a bit -- but will have to start in a while.

Comment: And Brandon, whose name I missed.

Comment: The curious thing was however, at the 1200 level the Chess.com tactical puzzles were more difficult -- I was hovering around 1100 on this site and touched 1300 on the Chess Tempo tactics site.  I guess it is also likely that the problem gradation in terms of elements of difficulty are different at different levels.  I can see what is meant when you say that sites have different rating systems.